# this.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get cards to flip over from back to front in a matching game and I am having trouble I am getting a console error and I am not sure why this is happening:
    at checkForMatch (main.js:27)
    at HTMLImageElement.flipCard (main.js:37)

Please look over my code and let me know what you see.
P.S. this is a pre course assignment for school that I am doing so I am not 100% familiar with some terms, but usually can understand what people are trying to say.
Thanks

```
var cards = [
{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
},
{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
},
{
    rank: "king",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"
},
{
    rank: "king",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
}
];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
    this.setAttribute('src', (cards.cardImage));
if (cardsInPlay.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]){
    alert("You found a match!");
} else {
        alert("Sorry, try again");
    }
}

var flipCard = function(){
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    checkForMatch();
    console.log("User flipped " + cards.rank);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards.rank);
    console.log(cards.cardImage);
    console.log(cards.suit);
}

var createBoard = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}

createBoard();
```

Comment: You could place a `debugger;` statement right in front of the line the code breaks and using the browser debugger tools (F12 in Chrome) check the values of your objects, set more breakpoints and see what happens where.

Comment: Update checkForMatch() to ► checkForMatch.bind(this)(); In addition this code ► `this.setAttribute('src', (cards.cardImage));` looks suspect. `cards` is an array so you need to specify the index, i.e: `cards[index].cardImage` I think you need to pass the `cardId`

Comment: I have been using the JS console in Chrome to figure out the issue, it lets me know where the problems are! Thanks

Comment: @Fran you're right, I did need to add the index for the array. It's weird though because it will now not show the front of the card after the 'flipCard', plus when I 'click' one card it acts as if there is already a card in the cardsInPlay[ ] array.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the context issue you can replace Update `checkForMatch()` with `checkForMatch.bind(this)();` but you also seem to have another issue in your code inside `checkForMath`, line ► `this.setAttribute('src', (cards.cardImage));` doesn't specify the index of the array you want the image from.

My guess is you wanted to pass the `cardId`, similar to this ► `checkForMatch.bind(this)(cardId);`

It seems your console logs are also not specifying an index and propably should be using the `cardId` as well ► `console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);` and `console.log(cards[cardId].suit);`

> I made all the changes below in a working example. As the images are
>   random for demonstration purpose and to sow actual images, use the
>   corrected console output for to see everything working correctly.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


  var cards = [{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "http://lorempixel.com/25/25/animals/"
  }, {
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "http://lorempixel.com/25/25/animals/"
  }, {
    rank: "king",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "http://lorempixel.com/25/25/animals/"
  }, {
    rank: "king",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "http://lorempixel.com/25/25/animals/"
  }];

  var cardsInPlay = [];

  var checkForMatch = function(cardId) {
    this.setAttribute('src', cards[cardId].cardImage);
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
      alert("You found a match!");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, try again");
    }
  }

  var flipCard = function() {
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    checkForMatch.bind(this)(cardId);
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards.rank);
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
  }

  var createBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
      cardElement.setAttribute('src', "http://lorempixel.com/25/25/animals/");
      cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
      cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
      document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
  }

  createBoard();
});
```

```css
img{
padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-board"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `this` parameter to the function.
Try this:

```
var checkForMatch = function(elem) {
    elem.setAttribute('src', (cards.cardImage));
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]){
        alert("You found a match!");
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, try again");
    }
}

var flipCard = function(elem){
    var cardId = elem.getAttribute('data-id');
    checkForMatch(elem);
    console.log("User flipped " + cards.rank);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards.rank);
    console.log(cards.cardImage);
    console.log(cards.suit);
}

var createBoard = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
            flipCard(this);
        });
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}

createBoard();
```

Comment: with the elem, the error changes to "cannot read property of setAttribute". Does that mean that I need to use something different instead like a getElementById before the setAttribute?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it. You need to pass it in eventlistener

Comment: You can also just update `checkForMatch()` to ► `checkForMatch.bind(this)();` instead of updating every single function. `flipCard` is the click event it already has context